# Send command with ASCII to USB port

Tags: java, command, usb

I need to send a command to the USB device. I tried a lot of examples, but without result. I do not know if the problem is in the structure of a command or send a command.
The structure is as follows \ x1B COMMAND \ n (without spaces Between command and marks).

Thank you for any advice or a better solution

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char ESC = (char) 27;
    char LN = (char) 10;
    String cmd = "command";
    String cmdString = ESC + cmd + LN;

    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        System.out.println(portList);
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/ttyUSB0")) {

                try {
                    serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleWriteApp", 2000);
                } catch (PortInUseException e) {

                }
                try {
                    outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
                try {
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                    ;
                }
                try {
                    outputStream.write(cmdString.getBytes());
                    outputStream.flush();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved. I used library JSSC https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector
There is simple source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char ESC = (char) 27; // Ascii character for Escape
    char LN = (char) 10;
    String message = "TX ENROLL:0 PGX:0 PGY:0 ALARM:0 BEEP:NONE";
    String cmd = ESC + message + LN;
    SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    try {

        serialPort.openPort();
        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_57600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
        serialPort.writeString(cmd);

        serialPort.closePort();
    } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```